# How to automate conversion from linear history without merge commits to linear history with merge commits?

Tags: git

How could I automate conversion from a repository that look like this (without merge commits, a single line - [screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKrwA.png)):

```
* 559b18e (HEAD -> feature-d) feature-d-commit-c
* 255defd feature-d-commit-b
* b0fab4c feature-d-commit-a
* bd13c11 (feature-c) feature-c-commit-c
* ad3c099 feature-c-commit-b
* 89396f4 feature-c-commit-a
* 4c6e6d9 (feature-b) feature-b-commit-c
* bfbef8f feature-b-commit-b
* 1bc98cc feature-b-commit-a
* 3711c5b (feature-a) feature-a-commit-c
* 36e0042 feature-a-commit-b
* 1e24bee feature-a-commit-a
* 6b02ead (master, dev) Initial Commit
```

into a repository that looks like this (with merge commits - [screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKlC1.png)):

```
*   d755428 (HEAD -> master, dev) Merge branch 'feature-d' into dev
|\  
| * e293b42 (feature-d) feature-d-commit-c
| * 1d8fb58 feature-d-commit-b
| * d00bbd5 feature-d-commit-a
|/  
*   758b701 Merge branch 'feature-c' into dev
|\  
| * c6b1e3c (feature-c) feature-c-commit-c
| * 5ecba0f feature-c-commit-b
| * 754245d feature-c-commit-a
|/  
*   6aa292a Merge branch 'feature-b' into dev
|\  
| * 7877571 (feature-b) feature-b-commit-c
| * 76ed497 feature-b-commit-b
| * 52d060b feature-b-commit-a
|/  
*   6635bd0 Merge branch 'feature-a' into dev
|\  
| * 3711c5b (feature-a) feature-a-commit-c
| * 36e0042 feature-a-commit-b
| * 1e24bee feature-a-commit-a
|/  
* 6b02ead Initial Commit
```

In the initial repository I create a linear history and a branch for each feature. When I finish with a feature, instead of merging 'dev' branch I like to develop a few more features instead so I can later review the history and reorder commits if necessary (it helps me understand later how what I'm developing is done and use the repository as a tutorial - I develop on my own). Once I'm happy with the history I proceed to rebase and merge until I get the final repository (it helps me to better identify which commits belong to which feature). Does this workflow make sense?

In this specific case, I can achieve what I want by doing:

```
git checkout dev
git merge --no-ff feature-a --no-edit

git checkout feature-b
git rebase dev
git checkout dev
git merge --no-ff feature-b --no-edit

git checkout feature-c
git rebase dev
git checkout dev
git merge --no-ff feature-c --no-edit

git checkout feature-d
git rebase dev
git checkout dev
git merge --no-ff feature-d --no-edit

git checkout master
git merge dev --no-edit
```

I think this could be easily automated (unless there is already a git command for this) with a script like this:

```
dev_branch="dev"
first_feature_branch="feature-a"

git checkout $dev_branch
git merge --no-ff $first_feature_branch --no-edit

for feature_branch in "feature-b" "feature-c" "feature-d"
do
    git checkout $feature_branch
    git rebase $dev_branch
    git checkout $dev_branch
    git merge --no-ff $feature_branch --no-edit
done

git checkout master
git merge $dev_branch --no-edit
```

I can pass `dev_branch` and `first_feature_branch` as arguments to the script, then I suppose that I would need to get a list of branches in between them (`feature-b` `feature-c` `feature-d`), which I don't know how to do or if it is possible.

I haven't been able to find a solution to my problem. All articles, answers and blogs seem to do merge commits before starting a new feature.

Comment: "*All articles, answers and blogs seem to do merge commits before starting a new feature.*" That is generally true of most devs workflows. It prevents really confusing scenarios like this. I don't think this question is really about git -- it sounds like you know enough to know how to approach this problem. It's really about bash scripting... how to process a list of params. Am I right?

Comment: I know how to process a list of params in a bash script. What I would like to know is how to ask git to tell me "which branches are in between 'dev' and 'feature-d'". This way I could use that list in the for loop and reuse the script for other similar situations. Obviously I could edit the script any time I needed to do this but reuse would be better.

Comment: Oh... You really want a script to make that decision for you? Seems like it might grab stuff you didn't want... half-finished feature branches, etc. I think modifying your workflow might nullify the need for this complicated script.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write your own script (and by the time you understand it properly and have built something that works, you may not want this script after all, but it's still a good exercise :-) ).

> I can pass `dev_branch` and `first_feature_branch` as arguments to the script, then I suppose that I would need to get a list of branches in between them (`feature-b feature-c feature-d`), which I don't know how to do or if it is possible.

It *is* possible, modulo one rather large problem: the definition of "between" is slippery.  Also, it probably makes more sense to provide a single "starting point" commit/branch-name, and then use `HEAD` as the ending one.

These are the key items:

- In Git, branch names are merely pointers, pointing to (storing the hash ID of) a single commit.  We call that commit the *tip* of the branch but as you have seen in your own repository, being the "tip of the branch" does not mean there are no further commits!
- Therefore, while we often talk about commits as being "on" some branch, any given commit can be on *many* branches simultaneously.  For instance your commit `1e24bee feature-a-commit-a` is on *all four* feature branches.  Meanwhile your commit `559b18e (HEAD -> feature-d) feature-d-commit-c` is only on one feature branch, `feature-d`.  It is also the current commit (`HEAD`) by virtue of the fact that ...
- The name `HEAD` contains the name of the current branch (well, normally anyway).  This is the case here: `HEAD` contains the name `feature-d`.  The name `feature-d` points to (contains the hash ID of) commit `559b18e`.  In effect, `HEAD` points to `feature-d`, and `feature-d` points to `559b18e`, which is what makes `559b18e` the current commit.

(It's possible to have a "detached HEAD", in which case `HEAD` contains the raw hash ID of a commit.  That commit may or may not have some branch names pointing directly to it, and may or may not be find-able by starting at some branch names and working backwards.  What Git does in general is to start at one or more branch names and/or at `HEAD`, and work backwards to find more commits.  Each commit stores its parent commit's hash ID, allowing this backwards method of finding all commits, starting from branch tip commits.)

Now, there are a bunch of useful Git tools for working with this.  The two key ones are:

- `git for-each-ref`: this is [the Swiss Army Chainsaw](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/swiss-army-chainsaw) version of `git tag` and `git branch` in their branch-and-tag-listing forms.  You can get a list of *all* branches with:

  ```
  git for-each-ref refs/heads
  ```

  (the `refs/heads` here gets a slash appended, and then refers to every *reference* in the `refs/heads/` name-space, which is where Git stores all its branches).
- `git rev-list`: this is the Swiss Army Chainsaw version of `git log`, intended for scripting.  (In fact, internally, both commands are built from the same source files.  They just set a few options differently so that one behaves better for humans, and the other behaves better for scripts.)

To find all branch names that point to commits "between"—again, this is a slippery notion in graph senses—some starting point and some ending point, you can use `git rev-list` to enumerate every commit in that range:

```
git rev-list --topo-order --reverse --ancestry-path ^start^@ end
```

for instance.  I'll leave the logic behind `--ancestry-path` and `^start^@` aside, since if you can guarantee a linear chain of commits, you can simplify this to just:

```
git rev-list --topo-order --reverse ^start^ end
```

The `start^` notation is described in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html): it means "the parent of `start`".  Assuming a nice, simple, linear chain of commits:

```
...--0--S--1--2--3--4--5--E   <-- end (HEAD)
```

If we find the hash ID of `S`, and ask `git rev-list` for `^S end`, we'll get a listing of commits `1 2 3 4 5 E` (one hash ID per line).  But we want to look at commit `S` too!  So we need to tell `git rev-list` to exclude, not `S`, but rather `S^`, which is commit `0`.

The `--topo-order` flag tells `git rev-list` to sort these in "topological" order: basically, child first, then parent.  (In fact, in this simple case it doesn't actually matter, because the default order is "priority queue" order with ties broken by date-stamps to produce chronological order, but there will be no ties in our simple linear chain.  It's still a good idea to keep the flag in, for future, more complex uses.)

The `--reverse` flag tells `git rev-list` to list the commits in the order we want: most-ancestral ("oldest") to least-ancestral ("newest").  As I noted in the parenthetical paragraph above, Git really likes to—in fact, it *has* to—work backwards, from a branch tip commit to its parent commits and then to the parent's parent, and so on.  Both `git log` and `git rev-list` work this way, though any time they could look at two commits "simultaneously", they need to do a little more work to pick which one to go with next.  In any case, `--reverse` makes them emit commits in reverse order, which in our case will wind up being "forward order" (the order in which you want to do your various Git operations).

So, now that we have the list of all candidate commits, the remaining problem is to see which branch(es) are interesting.  Here, you can run `git for-each-ref refs/heads` to list *all* branches and their commit IDs (see [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-for-each-ref.html) for ways to modify the default output to make it the most useful for your own case).  You can then figure out which commit IDs match those in the `git rev-list` output, and where they go.  That will give you a list of branch names you can operate upon.